# Is a braking rotation immediately after touching down a known maneuver?

Tags: landing, airliner, pilot-technique, grass-field

> [image]

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ivH7tLiFLY) the airliner landing on grass rotates high up after touching down, looks like more than it would do during take off. Is it a known possible way to drop the speed or it was more for the show? Is this maneuver ever used during more conventional landings?

Comment: Related: [Is aerodynamic braking really effective?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51834/14897)

Comment: Maybe it keeps the wheels from sinking in soft ground at high speed?

Comment: That aircraft is an Ilyushin Il-62 by Interflug, which was landed there by Heinz-Dieter Kallbach. It is now [a museum](https://www.otto-lilienthal.de/flugzeug-il-62.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bit of a bounce and skip at touchdown along with the nosewheel bouncing due to the uneven ground and aggressive landing.  He was probably doing it to hold the nosewheel off after the bounce, to reduce the main wheel contact force somewhat (the normal soft field landing technique) but it looks to me like he overcontrolled with the pitch a bit.

There will be relatively little braking friction so initially you would get better deceleration with the high pitch attitude, but that benefit declines quickly as you slow down and you quickly become reliant on braking and reversers (If the grass is wet, you have about as much braking as compacted, glazed snow, that is, not much; they would have to makes sure the ground was dry or he would have slid into the next field).

If you're on pavement, you want maximum braking as soon as possible, which means you want the lift dumpers out as soon as possible, so you wouldn't use that sort of technique; it's just get the mains on, then fly the nosewheel on, then hard on the brakes right away.  You'd have a longer landing run on pavement trying to land like that, plus there's too much risk of bouncing the whole thing back in the air just as the lift dumpers are extending or about to extend, which results in follow-on touchdown that will rattle teeth and blow tires.

Comment: The screenshot in the question looks like the spoilers are out (which prevents them from lifting off again, I suppose).

Comment: I watched it again and you're right they come out right away, maybe because the nosewheel touched and the logic was satisfied, or as I suspect, the airplane is Russian and has manually deployed lift dumpers with the copilot ready on the switch.  There was a CRJ landing a while back where there was a large bounce and the pilot advanced the thrust then changed his mind and pulled them back, while the "on-ground" logic was still active.  The lift dumpers came out when the thrust levers were pulled, while about 15 ft in the air and it free-fell to the ground and collapsed the main gear.